# Removing unwanted context menu items has backfired

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, context-menu

I dislike many of the extra entries in the context menu.

[image]

I downloaded [shexview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and [Easy Context Menu](https://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/), tools to remove context menu items. And it was glorious. I was deleting menu items left and right, no need to know exactly which item corresponds to which name, because those items probably deserved it anyway for what they did to me. Though I have to admit that the satisfaction of deleting these _______ items, at times, may have somewhat overpowered my ability to make careful judgments.

At first there was no indication of damage done. But the next day I made the discovery that **every time I click on an image file in the finder, the entire file explorer crashes.** This means I can't do anything with any images at all and my computer is basically a hidden minefield of crashes. The hangover after my pleasureful night had arrived. I tried going into both tools and re-enabling what I could, but some items had been deleted and not just disabled. I tried a system restore, but the problem persisted.

Have I completely screwed myself over, or is there some hope for saving my windows computer, short of backing up files and starting over completely?

Comment: Boot in safe mode and see if the problem persists or not.

Comment: run the app first ... open the image file using the app's file menu

Comment: every time I click on an image file in the finder, the entire file explorer crashes.    ..... The only way I know how to fix this kind of error is to run a Windows 11 Repair Install and Keep Data only.  You best hope your user profile is OK. If not, backup and reinstall is the only hope.

Comment: Did you disable or remove the shell entries? What does Event Viewer have to say about the crashes? Have you tried basic Windows repair steps?